# mysql show databases() only information_schema database

Tags: mysql

I use `mysql -u root -p` to login to mysql. Command `show databases` only shows information_schema database, and `current_user` is not root

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select current_user();
+----------------+
| current_user() |
+----------------+
| @localhost     |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Have you created any other databases? What are you expecting to see?

Comment: why not show the `mysql` database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no other databases - try to create one.

The current user is probably the anonymous user - by default MySQL ships with the following users, all having empty password (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/default-privileges.html)

[image]

Comment: but the `mysql` database is existing

Comment: Well, then try `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p` and check what is the current user ?